# How can I get data into HBase Hadoop Workflow

Tags: hadoop, schema, hbase

I am building a web analytics app I would like a low latency rest end point to take json and store this in hbase.

I have read about kafka & storm seems like a pretty good way to get data into hbase, it appears as if the data it handles is of a flat structure, I can not visualise how it would work with my use case.

As an example of the data I would be collecting is below in json

```
{
    page: "www.url.com/checkout.html",
    cat: "checkout"
    browser: "IE 6",
    ipAddress: "127.0.0.1",
    userId: 10000,
    session: 20000,
    timeOnPage: null,
    user: {
        name: "John", gender: "Male", age: 25, lat: 0.1, long: 0.1
    },
    purchased: {
        products: [
            { name: prod1, cost: 100 },
            { name: prod2, cost: 200 },
            { name: prod3, cost: 300 }
        ],
        total: 600
    },
    mouseMovement: [

    ]
}
```

As you can see the data is not a flat model, also some of the data will be updated at a later point in time.

I had imagined that this data structure would fit into hbase nicely as is? But maybe I am entirely wrong?

Comment: The question is: what kind of queries do you want to run against it.

Comment: The queries I would like to run ideally would be really flexible, much like Google analytics but with a full break down with customer data. I had thought I would also like reports such as top selling products and product recommendations. My end goal is to push everything to elastic search, to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

you can integrate hive with Hbase and use HiveQL for queries:

for exmple your Json File:

```
 {"id": 123, "name": "Ram", "role":"TeamLead"}
 {"id": 456, "name": "Silva", "role":"Member"}
 {"id": 789, "name": "Krishna", "role":"Member"}
```

You can use the `get_json_object` function to parse the data as a JSON object. For instance, if you create a staging table with your JSON data:

```
CREATE TABLE staging (json STRING);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/local/path/to/jsonfile' INTO TABLE staging;
```

Then use `get_json_object` to extract the attributes you want to load into the table:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hbase_table_emp SELECT
  get_json_object(json, "$.id") AS id,
  get_json_object(json, "$.name") AS name,
  get_json_object(json, "$.role") AS role
FROM staging;
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Ok so I could use kafka to stream the raw json data into a hbase log table, then constantly process to separate table.

Comment: I have no idea what kafka is ! but what I'm trying to tell you here is that you can do the same by integrating hbase and hive.http://hadooptutorial.info/hbase-integration-with-hive/#Setup_for_HBase_Integration_with_Hive

Comment: I am pretty new to all of this but I have found this company a really useful resource http://hortonworks.com/ you can download their sand box VM and has everything setup for you, thought it may be of interest to you.

Comment: Actually "Cloudera" , "Hortonworks" and "MapR" are Hadoop Distributions